# Public files/folders inside a private Github repo?

Tags: github

Is it possible to only make certain parts of a private github repo public? This would be a useful feature if you just want to demo certain parts of your code, etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GitHub don't allow this feature as your desire. I have a trick (but you must re-structure folder/project):

Create repo `Pr` is private.

Create repo `Pr1` is private module 1.

Create repo `Pu2` is public module 2 what you want share.

Add 2 sub-modules are `Pr1` and `Pu2` to `Pr`.

Result: `Pr` is private, but module `Pu2` is public. It's exactly what you want.

**Reference**

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules